# Force a field value of a razor page during ASP.NET server-side validation

Tags: asp.net-core, validation, razor-pages

How can I force a field to have a default value during server-side validation of a razor page?

I tried with this example code but it doesn't work: what am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

```
public class SetDefaultValueWhenEmptyAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private string defaultValue;

    public SetDefaultValueWhenEmptyAttribute(string defaultValue)
    {
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult? IsValid(object? value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var instObj = validationContext.ObjectInstance;
        var instType = instObj.GetType();

        if (value == null)
        {
            var currProp = instType.GetProperty(validationContext.MemberName);

            if (currProp != null)
            {
                Type currType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(currProp.PropertyType) ?? currProp.PropertyType;
                object safeValue = Convert.ChangeType(defaultValue, currType);
                currProp.SetValue(instObj, safeValue);
            }

            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

This is the model:

```
    public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = nameof(ValidationMessages.Required), ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages))]
    public string Title { get; set; } = null!;

    [StringLength(250, MinimumLength = 5)]
    public string Description { get; set; } = null!;

    [Display(Name = "Genere film")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [SetDefaultValueWhenEmpty("Example", ErrorMessage = "Value forced")]
    public string? Genre { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Year go")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [Range(2000, 2100)]
    public int YearGo { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    [Range(1, 100)]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to set the Genre field with the defualt value of SetDefaultValueWhenEmpty attribute if field is empty.

When the field is empty I force the default value and then return an error to display the forcing message but the field remains empty on the screen.
In debug I see the Genre property set to the default value but not on screen.

Comment: Why don't you simply assign a value to the target property in the PageModel?

Comment: Hi Mike, because I would like to report the forcing of the field before the user proceeds with confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got what you mean

assuming a model like:

```
public class TargetObj
{

    public int Id { get; set; }


    [SetDefaultValueWhenEmpty("s")]

    public string? TargetField { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

> the field remains empty on the screen

just because asp.net core render the Page accroding to the value inside the ModelState,but you haven't update the model state

Try call the codes in your handler

```
ModelState.SetModelValue("Obj.TargetField", new ValueProviderResult(Obj.TargetField));
```

Now it was dispalyed on the page:
[image]

However when you try with a customer validator,it's hard for you to access ModelState directly(It's designed for validation not binding),I still suggest you try with  custom model binder,you could access modelstate ,bind the value and add the error(it's allowed to add errors during modelbing,for example,when  you pass "" to server and bind it to int type,it would be considered as an invalid value)

```
public class SetDefaultValueWhenEmptyBinder : IModelBinder
{
   
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        
          ........
            bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(......);
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(....)
           
        }

        
        return Task.CompletedTask;

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ruikai,
thanks for your help.
In fact it may seem confusing but the purpose of forcing a field with a default value during validation is to highlight the forcing before the user's final confirmation.
That is: is the field empty? yes, then I report the error but at the same time force it to the default value.
It seemed to me that the best place was to do this during validation.

Comment: are you binding value to field instead of property? would you modify it to property which has a setter?

Comment: I would like the field with the custom attribute to display the default value on the screen. In debug I see that the field value is set correctly but it is not displayed on the screen.

Comment: When the field is empty I force the default value and then return an error to display the forcing message but the field remains empty on the screen.  If I don't return the error, the value is set correctly, it is inserted into the database but the message is not displayed.

Comment: Hi,@steve fax,I've got what you mean and updated my answer,please check it

Comment: That is: is the field empty? yes, then I report the error but at the same time force it to the default value--- this could be done during model-binding,you could reprot the error as a binding error

Comment: Ruikai, thank you for your help.